# how to save message content to text file

Tags: android

I have an application that reads incoming and outgoing sms. Logcat successfully show recieved and send messages. here is my code.

```
  String[] columns = new String[]{"address", "date", "body", "type"};
  String recipient = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
  String date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
  String message = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
  String type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
  Log.d("DetectOutgoingSMS", recipient + " , " + date + " , " + message + " , " +type);
```

Now I want to save all the above strings to a textfile.  I tried below code to write it to text file.

```
  try {
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("textfile.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
//---write the string to the file---
osw.write(message);
osw.close();
//---display file saved message---
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Using this code I am unable to save all strings in one go. An when new message is recieved, previous is deleted from textfile and new messeage is inserted. Any help please.

Comment: What do you mean by "save all strings in one go"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to "save" the Strings, or "write" the Strings?

To "Save" the strings you need to use `onPause()` or `onSavedInstanceState()`. There are plenty of tutorials online to help you with that, depending on your goal.

To "Write" the Strings all at once you can use this.

```
String[] columns = new String[]{"address", "date", "body", "type"};
String recipient = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
String date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
String message = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
String type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
String all = ("OutgoingSMS: " + recipient + " , " + date + " , " + message + " , " +type);
```

Then replace this

```
osw.write(message);
```

with this

```
osw.write(all);
```

If you need anything else, or I misunderstood what you need, just ask

Comment: Thanks was missing this simple line
String all = ("OutgoingSMS: " + recipient + " , " + date + " , " + message + " , " +type);

Comment: @RidaShahid yep, you're welcome. You were posting it to the `log` with `Log.d`, you just weren't saving it as a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

change MODE_PRIVATE to MODE_APPEND

Comment: Although in this particular case, replacing the flags is ok (because MODE_PRIVATE = 0), it would be less clear to do so. Rather, keep both flags with a bitwise operation: MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_APPEND.